# What is "an increasing sequence of step functions"?

Tags: definition, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading Alan Weir's "*Lebesgue Integration and Measure*".

In exercise 8 on page 30 he talks about "...*an increasing sequence of step functions* $\{\phi_n\}$..." and "...*an increasing sequence of sets* $\{S_n\}$..." However, he doesn't seem to define what these are.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An increasing sequence of functions is a sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ such that $\phi_{n+1}(x)\geq\phi_n(x)$ for all $x$ and $n$. An increasing sequence of sets $\{S_n\}$ has the property that $S_n\subseteq S_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The first one means a pointwise increasing sequence of step functions.
He is probably approximating a function from below by a pointwise increasing sequence of step functions so that the limit is almost everywhere the desired function.

An increasing sequence of sets means a nested sequence of sets: every set contains the previous one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Joonas. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @FlybyNight, you are most welcome. :)